# How to use NSUserDefault with several preferenses and textColor

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults, textcolor

I have a UISwitch, witch among other things, disables a UITextfield.
When using NSUserDefaults, I manage the switch to remember its current state (on/off)

```
NSString *const MyPrefKey =@"MyPrefKey";


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setBool:[sender isOn]
     forKey:MyPrefKey];
```

The switch state is recalled in viewDidLoad with

```
 BOOL switchState =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:MyPrefKey];
 [mySwitch setOn:switchState];
```

This works perfect, the position of the UISwitch is remembered.

For enabling the textfield when the switch changed

I tried as suggested:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[myTextField isEnabled]]
     forKey:MyPrefKey];
```

and recalled with

```
BOOL mtf  =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:MyPrefKey];
[myTextField setEnabled:mtf];
```

Which also worked fine.
However, only one of these work at the time. How do I make more defaults to be set at the same time? Do I have to make several PrefKeys? or can all of them be stored in the same prefKey?

Finally I tried to change the textcolor with NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject: [myTextField textColor]
     forKey: MyPrefKey];
```

that causes a crash when recalled with

```
UIColor*newColor= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: EfloraSharePrefKey];
[myTextField setTextColor:newColor];
```

So how do I use NSUserDefault with textColor? I would appriciate any good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save property list objects only to NSUserDefaults. You have to somehow serialize your color. A possible solution:

```
CGFloat r, g, b, a;
[myTextField.textColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
NSNumber *rn, *gn, *bn, *an;
rn = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:r];
gn = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:g];
bn = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:b];
an = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:a];
NSDictionary *color = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    rn, @"red",
    gn, @"green",
    bn, @"blue",
    an, @"alpha",
    nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:color forKey:@"TextColor"];
```

And to retrieve it:

```
NSDictionary *color = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TextColor"];
NSNumber *rn, *gn, *bn, *an;
rn = [color objectForKey:@"red"];
...
UIColor *c = [UIColor colorWithRed:[rn floatValue]
    green:[gn floatValue]
    blue:[bn floatValue]
    alpha:[an floatValue]];
textField.textColor = c;
```

If you want to be really elegant, you can wrap this into a category and even make UIColor NSCoding-comformant (in order to be able to directly persist it to the user defaults plist).

Comment: Thank you. This was VERY helpfull and this killed a lot of frustration. Also, I have still problems understanding the point with "NSString *const MyPrefKey =@"MyPrefKey";" which I found in a textbook. Is this really neccesary?

Comment: Also...I still don't seem to get it. I have a UISwitch that disables a textfield and changes the text color. I now have working methods for all these three parameters. But only one of then will work at the time. They all have different keys. How can I get around this problem, and make all of them be stored with NSUserDefaaults simultaniously?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSKeyedUnarchiver to archive/unarchive the data of the UIColor. Save the NSData as an object for the NSUserDetaults. Create the NSData from the color using

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourColor];
```

and unarchive it using

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:yourColorKey]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like H2C03 said, you need to make it a valid property list item.  Hover, some colors are not in the RGB color space.  However, you can put NSData in a plist, and UIColor supports archiving.

```
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
```

then on the other side...

```
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
```